# Registering an imported component in vue app

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I'm attempting to use a NPM package `vue-simple-spinner` in my Vue CLI webpack app, but I am getting error:

`Unknown custom element: <vue-simple-spinner> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

The docs say:
[image: vue-simple-spinner docs]

So I included this in my `main.js` file like so:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import Spinner from 'vue-simple-spinner'

import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: {
    App,
    Spinner
  },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

Then the docs say:

[image: vue-simple-spinner docs 2]

I've included the `<vue-simple-spinner></view-simple-spinner>` tags but I'm not sure where / how to include the js scripts. I've tried including them in the template (gives an error) and also tried importing the component using `import Spinner from 'vue-simple-spinner` as in  but both attempts are still giving me the `Unknown custom element` error.

How do I include the scripts and/or properly register the component?

This is my full Vue.app file:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <div>
      <h1>Market Price Spreads</h1>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="loadMarkets()">Refresh Markets</button>
      <vue-simple-spinner></vue-simple-spinner>
    </div>
    <div class="main-table">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Market</th>
            <th>Poloniex</th>
            <th>Bittrex</th>
            <th>Spread</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="market in markets">
              <td>{{ market[0] }}</td>
              <td>{{ market[1] | round(6) }}</td>
              <td>{{ market[2] | round(6)}}</td>
              <td>{{ market[3] | round(2)}} %</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
  /* eslint-disable */

  import loadDataMixin from './components/mixins/loadDataMixin'

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    mixins: [loadDataMixin],
    filters: {
      round: function(number, places) {
        return number.toFixed(places)
      }
    },
  }
</script>

<style>
  #app {
    font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    color: #2c3e50;
    margin-top: 60px;
  }
  
  .main-table {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
components: {
  Spinner
}
```

is shorthand for

```
components: {
  Spinner: Spinner
}
```

which means your component would be registered as `<spinner>`.  Try:

```
components: {
  'vue-simple-spinner': Spinner
}
```

Comment: You mean `Spinner: Spinner` ?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I guess yes that would be it.  But in Vue component names are automatically converted to snake case, so `<spinner>` is how it would get registered ultimately.  Thanks for the note I edited for correctness

Comment: Thanks but I tried that and still receiving the error `Unknown custom element: <vue-simple-spinner> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

Comment: Nevermind that worked when I moved the component property to App.vue from main.js